# Why Constants in Flow has Value as optional?

Tags: visual-workflow

I'm building Flows for the first time and I'm unable to find the reason why Constants have their Value set to optional when it's being created. I don't think we have another way to assign a value to the constant after it gets created.

Can someone please help me understand? Google/Trailhead/Help docs are of no use.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you really do mean to have an "empty" value, such as the property `$GlobalConstant.EmptyString` would be defined. I agree that I'd probably never use this in production, but it might be useful in some limited circumstances, perhaps to disable some logic without entirely dismantling it.

Comment: Makes sense. $GlobalConstant.EmptyString would represent an empty sting while no value represents NULL I guess. Thanks for your inputs.